# Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem in NodeJS using an array.map?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I make the following code more elegant?

```
let theUrls = [];
data.urlset.map((url) => {
  theUrls.push({
    url: url.loc ? url.loc[0] : "",
    date: url.date ? url.date[0] : "",
  });
});
return theUrls;
```

Comment: Why do you need `[].concat(sites)` instead of just `return sites`?

Comment: I believe the second segment is OP's code. The first segment is code they're using from an unnamed module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any loop that simply pushes a value onto a result array can be done with `map`. Just return the object that you're pushing.

```
const vals = data.urlset.url.map(url => ({
  url: url.loc ? url.loc[0] : null,
  lastmod: url.lastmod ? url.lastmod[0] : null
}));
return vals;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *optional chaining* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and *nullish coalescing* operators (`?.` and `??` respectively):

```js
const urls = data.urlset.map( url =>
  ({
    url  : url?.loc?.[0]     ?? '' ,
    date : url?.lastmod?.[0] ?? '' ,
  })
);
```

Even more elegant if you can default to `undefined` for missing values:

```js
const urls = data.urlset.map( url =>
  ({
    url  : url?.loc?.[0]     ,
    date : url?.lastmod?.[0] ,
  })
);
```